# Ember.js Model - Custom Errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting a list of courses from the server and I need to handle different kind of custom errors.

This is how I set the model and how I catch the error, the problem is that I can't send a custom message for the error:

```
App.CoursesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
      return this.store.find('course').then(function(response) {
        return response;
      }, function(error) {
        // need to retrieve error message
    });
  }
});
```

This is the model for the Courses

```
App.Course = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  teachers: attr('string')
});
```

This is de JSON that matches the courses model

```
{"courses":[{"name":"My Course","teachers":"2"},{"name":"Other Course","teachers":"3"}]}
```

I've tried many things like creating a Model for Errors and sending a JSON like this but nothing works...

```
App.Error = DS.Model.extend({
  message: attr('string')
});

{"error":[{"message":"No courses found"}]}
```

Comment: is there are reason why your not using `DS.attr('string')` and just `attr('string')`?

Comment: @agconti I think it's been shortned like `var attr = DS.attr` then you just use the `attr` reference (which could be named anything other than `attr` btw)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe yeah that could work. I'm just surprised because its not anywhere in the OP's code.

Comment: @Gigin could you please post what comes in `error` in your `CourseRoute`? can you `console.log(error)` in that callback and paste here?